# how to store current_date in user variable

Tags: mysql

Why can't I write like this?

> set @date = SELECT CURRENT_DATE;

and how do i store return value of CURRENT_DATE in user variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
set @MYVAR = Current_date();
SELECT @MYVAR;
```